# Using batch to verify a process is running with WMIC

Tags: virtualbox, batch, automation, find, wmic

I am attempting to write a script that will check if a process is running (in my case a virtual machine)

```
@echo off
wmic process where name="VirtualBox.exe" | find "GitHubEnterprise" /c > tmpcount
set /p count= < tmpcount
echo Number of instances = %count%
```

So doing this allows me to see whether my instance of GitHub is running or not but it requires that I am able to write the output of find to a file then read it back in and delete the file.  (It should be noted that there are two copies of VirtualBox.exe running at anytime so I am attempting to verify that the GitHubEnterprise instance is running).

What I would like to do is store this count number from the find directly into a variable or use it in some form of an if statement.

Now from my own research on this I've seen many suggestions of using a `for` loop for this and I have attempted it in the following manner with no success:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
'wmic process where "name='VirtualBox.exe'" ^| find "GitHubEnterprise" /c'
) do ( 
@set count = %a
)
echo Number of instances = %count%
pause
endlocal
```

Can anyone see / tell me what I am doing incorrectly here or make a suggestion to do this better.

Thanks everyone, have a great day.

JD

Comment: Could you just write a startup & shutdown script on the GitHubEnterprise? Have it call home/email you whenever the virtualbox os is started or shutdown? It would be nice if we knew exactly what you are trying accomplish...

Comment: It's a script that runs every 5 minutes to make sure that the GitHubEnterprise VM is up and running.  If it's not it attempts to start it back up.  I already have this working currently but I want to remove the dependency of writing the variable value to a file then reading it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SETX,

Set environment variables, [SETX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx) can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU):

Set the variable _my_count to '5' in the users environment:

> SetX _my_count 5

then read the environment variable later...

> IF "%_my_count%" == "" GOTO DOTHIS

another way would to use the registry and the REG command.

Comment: Can you show how to do this using a for loop with the `wmic process where "name='VirtualBox.exe'" ^| find "GitHubEnterprise" `command